# Install Redis-Commander as service on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: ubuntu, redis, ubuntu-19.04

I created my self a virtual machine with an Ubuntu 19.04 guest system running redis and redis commander.

I can access the redis commander via 8081 but need to start it manually everytime I start the VM.

How would I install the redis-commander as linux service? I would like to keep it directly installed in Ubuntu and not running in a docker container.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. I had the same issue but on Centos 7. In `/etc/systemd/system` directory you should create `.service` file, for example, `my-redis-commader.service`. The content of file is like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Redis Commander Activator
After=network.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/usr/lib/node_modules/redis-commander/bin/
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /usr/lib/node_modules/redis-commander/bin/redis-commander.js

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

where

`/usr/bin/node` - node.js executable file

`/usr/lib/node_modules/redis-commander/bin/redis-commander.js` - is the file of node.js module, which run the web application - gui for redis server.

Then run:

```
systemctl enable my-redis-commander.service
systemctl start my-redis-commander.service
```

Check status:

```
systemctl status my-redis-commander.service
```